# Latin for "vexatious Litigant"

Tags: motto, legal-latin

My days of decent knowledge of Latin are a little in the past since I passed my Latinum, and I am trying to get a good translation for what modern US courts call "[vexatious litigant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexatious_litigation)" into Latin for a little joke to a lawyer friend of mine - because illnesses have often Latin names and there's a lot of law-Latin around, just not the "vexatious litigant". I was planning to use this construction in combination with the imperative of abstain for the goal of "keep away the vexatious litigant".

The best translation for the word vexatious I could find is the root of it: vexatio, vexationis in its 4th meaning of "trouble, vexation".

Now Litigant also has a fitting Latin stem in litigere, litigo, in its 2nd meaning "to litigate/sue".

But here I get to the end of my Latin: How to properly combine the two to get the vexatious litigant?

Comment: Does "vexatious" have a specific legal meaning? I can think of plenty of Latin words for "annoying" etc, but I'm not sure if there's a specific connotation you need.

Comment: the term "vexatious litigant" is a term of art and as such has a specific meaning, yes. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexatious_litigation#United_States) has the california variant of the law explained. In canada the term is different but I fail to remember how.

Comment: @Draconis I don't think the term existed in roman time (roman-law) but legal-latin fits.

Answer (score 2):

A litigand is *litigator*. For "vexatious" you could use *vexabilis* or *vexativus* (both exist according to Lewis&Short). So you could say **litigator vexabilis** or **litigator vexativus**.